# using thin for long-polling connection

Tags: ruby, comet, long-polling, thin

since it's threadless, would the ruby-based thin be okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to do async connections, return -1 as your response code and do some stuff with event machine deferrables.

check out the async [thin examples](http://github.com/macournoyer/thin/tree/master/example/) for more info.