# Using ruby with thin for live chat functionality

Tags: ruby-on-rails, long-polling, thin, livechat

So my goal is to create some sort of simple chat functionality, and after a few days (that's right days) with no conclusive direction to go, I've decided to post it here. Basically all I need is a global chat channel that any user on the site can open up and contribute. I think I should be using long-polling.  I'd like to know if this can be accomplished using what I have now for the site: Ruby on Rails framework, with Backbone.js on top, also using thin gem for server junk. The only question on SO close to what I'm trying to accomplish is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072480/using-thin-for-long-polling-connection), but it is an incredibly vague answer. Keep it simple please, while I am pretty well off in most ruby and javascript stuff, this server side event business is basically brand new to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recomend you to try to use private_pub gem https://github.com/ryanb/private_pub
It's using Faye server, and it's easy to use and pretty fast